# App Waiting for review straight to Ready for Sale

Tags: ios, app-store

My app got rejected a couple days ago and I resubmitted it last night. I got an email saying its "Waiting for review" at 1:08am, then I woke up this morning and it says its "Ready for sale" in iTunes Connect. I never got an email saying its "In review". I still don't see it on the app store however.

Is this normal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's app review process instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 1):

I have had times when I didn't get an email for the "In Review" stage, if the app is marked ready for sale then it has been approved. It might take a few hours or so for it to appear in the AppStore search. You should be able to go to the information about the app and click "view in AppStore" towards the bottom if you would like

Comment: Got it, was a bit of a shock seeing "Ready for sale".